# Scrolling index.html to #contact after form submission (django)

Tags: html, django, scroll

index.html

```
<section id="contact">
   <form id="contactForm" method="get" action="{% url 'contact-form' %}">
   ...
      <button class="btn btn-common" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
</section>
```

where {% url 'contact-form' %} expands to contact-form/

After submitting this form, I want the page to scroll to #contact where the form is located(if there are form validation errors).

I've tried

```
$("#contactForm").submit( function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

But the scroll doesn't work.

Comment: Submitting the form will make the user's browser perform a GET request to you contact-form URL, this will cause the browser to load another page. If you wish the user to stay on the same page you will have to submit the form with an AJAX request

Answer (score 1):

Submitting a form loads another page, so the `$("#contactForm").submit( function()` is wiped away as soon as it is called.

Change your `{% url 'contact-form' %}` to `{% url 'contact-form' %}#contactForm` might do the trick for you.